# How do I check constraints on table columns using Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, constraints

If I don't use the `annotate` gem, how do I check the constrains that are on my table's columns? I can use rails console to see what columns are on which tables but I can't see the constraints like `not null`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Any ActiveRecord subclass has `columns` method, that returns all metadata about columns for underlying table:

```
User.columns.find { |c| c.name == 'email' }.null
# => false
```

Comment: thanks @MikDiet! have you heard of just using `bundle exec rake db` and that would get you into the psql console? someone showed me that but I wasn't really able to follow

Answer (score 2):

Without `annotate`, the easiest way from vim/text editor would be to look in the `db/schema.rb` file. This file is a culmination of all of your migrations and represents the current state of your database schema.

It will look very similar to a migration file. Here's an example:

```
ActiveRecord::Schema.define(:version => 11) do
  create_table "users", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "email", default: "", null: false
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
    t.string   "remember_token"
    t.datetime "remember_token_expires_at"
  end
end
```

As you can see on the `email` column, it may not be null (`not null`). Some other parameters may look like `limit: 20` for character limits, etc. [More column definitions are provided in the docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/ConnectionAdapters/TableDefinition.html#method-i-column)

Comment: The file db/schema.rb does not give reliable information about the state of the database structure.

The schema only shows how the database should be structured. If the schema has not been maintained in Git or the developer has made changes to the database on the console or via various database management tools, then the db/schema.rb file is no longer an up-to-date image of the database. Therefore, the only reliable method - as mentioned above - is to query the database directly via Rails or to use a tool for this purpose (e.g. pgAdmin, depending on the DBMS).